# Can outgoing job counts be controlled in tibco bw and how?

Tags: tibco-topic

I have a requirement: the backend can accept only 20 parallel request at a time. It is shared by many other clients and so it is not dedicated.

I have 100 ready request to be sent to the backend, but according to the requirement only 20 request should reach the backend.

How can I controll number of request send to the backend?

I checked tibco bw administrator and found that only load on start up process can be controlled with max job count properties that is incoming messages.

How would tibco do the controlling for out going requests count? Is there any controlling  max job count parameter for this or any external way?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it has to do with your Business Logic. However you may not ant to control the Process's thread creation in this. You may want to be little creative and may want to design two different process.
One to receive the request and Log into DB and other to pick specific 20 whatever jobs and send it to backed.

Moreover, you haven't specify if you want to use SOAP over HTTP or JMS. Over JMS we have more options to control this scenario without introducing 2nd process.

hope it may help.